# Jar файл архивация

Tags: jar

Коллеги, подскажите как лучше заархивировать дирректория в jar, без компрессии ?

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью командной строки и утилиты `jar`. Параметр 0 (нуль) указывает не сжимать файлы, записывая их в архив.  Например, следующая команда

```
jar cfv0 test.jar test.txt
```

создаст архив без компрессии, а команда

```
jar cfv1 test.jar test.txt
```

создаёт архив с компрессией.